# Eclipse CDT to compile ASF makefile projects

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, atmel

I'm attempting to set up Eclipse CDT as my development tool for ASF (ATMEL/MICROCHIP SAM0 micros) on debian stretch, but I'm running into a bunch of headaches.

Having Eclipse Oxygen, arm-none-eabi-gcc 5.4.1 and the Eclipse GCC ARM plugging properly installed I proceeded as follows:

First of all I downloaded [xdk-asf-3.34.2](https://spaces.atmel.com/gf/project/asf/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=4) and extracted the package on **/home/user/Downloads**. Inside the package there are some application examples, I'm using a SAMD20 Xplained-Pro board so I went to **sam0/applications/led_toggle** where there is a source code "led_toggle.c". There are also other meaninful files, asf.h, config.mk and Makefile in **sam0/applications/led_toggle/samd20_xplained_pro/gcc**.
I copied those files to an other directory inside Eclipse workspace. Making some modifications to the paths on config.mk and Makefile and creating a new project on eclipse with File>New>C Project>Makefile Project>Empty Project>Cross ARM GCC, the project finally compiled and the .elf file was ready.

Anyway Eclipse was highlighting syntax errors. Adding a lot of paths (the same paths as those on the INC_PATH of the config.mk file) to the Eclipse project (properties>C/C++ General>Paths and Symbols) and adding some defines to led_toggle.c (***#define BOARD SAMD20_XPLAINED_PRO*** and ***#define __SAMD20J18__***)
solved error highlighting but autocomplete is not working yet. Also format and colors are weird, here a screenshot.

[image]

For example, here the macro expansion for ***LED_0_PIN*** works, but font isn't blue as it is with ***PORT_PIN_DIR_OUTPUT***. But is autocomplete functionality which really annoys me, because with a big API to be used, autocomplete is a must have tool.

Should I give up and use Atmel Studio and ... Windows?

Comment: I use eclipse for my non SAM ARM projects and AS for ATMEL projects. But Atmel Cortex micros are very disappointing, full of bugs and relatively expensive. I use in my projects STM or freescale. Much better and  cheaper

Comment: Maybe but at this point the project I'm working at is already on an advanced state and changing the micro is not an option. I'd have go with STM too, but wasn't my choice.